# Can we render the Tiny MCE 5 toolbar menu items horizontally of a specific menu button?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-react

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4ajw.png)

Can we render the [menu items](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/typesoftoolbarbuttons/#menubutton)(Menu Item1, Menu Item 2, and Toggle menu item) horizontally without overriding the CSS of the `tox-collection__group` class?

Is there any way to use custom css classes for tiny MCE styling?

Thank you in advance

As far as I checked the documentation, I haven't found anything regarding passing custom css classes. May be I am missing something or it is not possible.

Comment: We can not do any specific styling for a particular button. However, keeping the `editor` object as a state and controlling it from reacting is better.